# TLS with MySQL by zabbix agent 2

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I try to use TLS for the mysql connection in the zabbix agent 2 with the "MySQL by zabbix agent 2" template.

Settings in the `{$MYSQL.DSN}` like `tcp://mariadb.fqdn.de:3306/?tls=skip-verify` has no effects.

There is also a config file `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.d/plugins.d/mysql.conf` where

`Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.*.TLSConnect=required` can be configured.

However, the `*` must be replaced with a session name. see

- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/extensions/plugins
- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agent2_plugins/mysql_plugin

however, I've no idea what the session name must look like.

In the host configuration I've changed the "Host Name" from `mariadb.fqdn.de` to `MariadbProd` and tried `Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.MariadbProd.TLSConnect=required`

After restarting the zabbix agent 2, it still connects just via `TCP/IP` in `SELECT *  FROM performance_schema.threads where PROCESSLIST_USER  = 'zbx_monitor' ;`

Answer (score 0):

You define what the session name is. That way you can monitor multiple MySQL instances with one agent.

For example, in your agent config file (or in a *.conf file in the /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.d folder) you can define a prod and test server as follows:

```
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Prod.Uri=tcp://192.168.1.1:3306
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Prod.User=<UserForProd>  
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Prod.Password=<PasswordForProd>
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Prod.TLSConnect=verify_full
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Prod.TLSCAFile=/path/to/ca_file
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Prod.TLSCertFile=/path/to/cert_file
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Prod.TLSKeyFile=/path/to/key_file
  
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Test.Uri=tcp://192.168.0.1:3306
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Test.User=<UserForTest>   
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Test.Password=<PasswordForTest>
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Test.TLSConnect=verify_ca
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Test.TLSCAFile=/path/to/test/ca_file
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Test.TLSCertFile=/path/to/test/cert_file
Plugins.Mysql.Sessions.Test.TLSKeyFile=/path/to/test/key_file
```

See https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/src/go/plugins/mysql/README.md

You then create two hosts in Zabbix, one for each MySQL. The Agent interface would be the ip of the host with the agent configuration above. Link the 'MySQL by zabbix agent 2' template to the host and set the value of the {$MYSQL.DSN} macro to match the Session name.